# Find all positive integers $m$, such that $n^4+m$ is not prime for any positive integer $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all positive integers $m$, such that $n^4+m$ is not prime for any positive integer $n$.

I know a form such $m=4k^4$ ,because it is well known [Sophie Germain's Identity](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml)

I conjecture this problem  have other form is also the answer?
and this problem is base the 1969 International Mathematical Olympiad problem 1:see [1969IMO](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60050p363654)

Comment: It is true that for $m = 4k^4$ the expression is composite by Sophie Germain's identity, but this does not show that this finds __all__ such $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the proof is pretty easy, part of it anyway. We know $x^4 + m$ has no real roots with $m >0.$ The possible factorization is then
$$ (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 - ax + b) = x^4 + m. $$
This gives us $2b = a^2,$ so $a$ is even, take $a = 2 t,$ then $a^2 = 4 t^2 = 2 b, $ then $b = 2 t^2$ and $m = b^2 = 4 t^4.$

The missing ingredient: **I do not know how to prove** that an irreducible monic polynomial does, at least once, assume a prime value. EDIT: this is an open problem, no proof available, see https://oeis.org/A225766  and related https://oeis.org/A225768

It appears that the $4 k^2$ (with $k \geq 2$) are the only (positive) constants that work, but I think a proof of that is far from trivial. Here is output, you can see how only 64 and 324 say "all composite." However, I do not see any pattern in the primes found.

different run: the 4 k^4 are the only successes for $m \leq 1000000$

======================================

```
 m   64 =  2^6  all composite  
 m   324 =  2^2 3^4  all composite  
 m   1024 =  2^10  all composite  
 m   2500 =  2^2 5^4  all composite  
 m   5184 =  2^6 3^4  all composite  
 m   9604 =  2^2 7^4  all composite  
 m   16384 =  2^14  all composite  
 m   26244 =  2^2 3^8  all composite  
 m   40000 =  2^6 5^4  all composite  
 m   58564 =  2^2 11^4  all composite  
 m   82944 =  2^10 3^4  all composite  
 m   114244 =  2^2 13^4  all composite  
 m   153664 =  2^6 7^4  all composite  
 m   202500 =  2^2 3^4 5^4  all composite  
 m   262144 =  2^18  all composite  
 m   334084 =  2^2 17^4  all composite  
 m   419904 =  2^6 3^8  all composite  
 m   521284 =  2^2 19^4  all composite  
 m   640000 =  2^10 5^4  all composite  
 m   777924 =  2^2 3^4 7^4  all composite  
 m   937024 =  2^6 11^4  all composite  
 m   1119364 =  2^2 23^4  all composite
```

=========================================

```
 m 1  n 1 prime  2
 m 2  n 1 prime  3
 m 3  n 2 prime  19
 m 4  n 1 prime  5
 m 5  n 6 prime  1301
 m 6  n 1 prime  7
 m 7  n 2 prime  23
 m 8  n 3 prime  89
 m 9  n 10 prime  10009
 m 10  n 1 prime  11
 m 11  n 6 prime  1307
 m 12  n 1 prime  13
 m 13  n 2 prime  29
 m 14  n 165 prime  741200639
 m 15  n 2 prime  31
 m 16  n 1 prime  17
 m 17  n 12 prime  20753
 m 18  n 1 prime  19
 m 19  n 20 prime  160019
 m 20  n 3 prime  101
 m 21  n 2 prime  37
 m 22  n 1 prime  23
 m 23  n 6 prime  1319
 m 24  n 35 prime  1500649
 m 25  n 2 prime  41
 m 26  n 3 prime  107
 m 27  n 2 prime  43
 m 28  n 1 prime  29
 m 29  n 90 prime  65610029
 m 30  n 1 prime  31
 m 31  n 2 prime  47
 m 32  n 3 prime  113
 m 33  n 8 prime  4129
 m 34  n 5 prime  659
 m 35  n 12 prime  20771
 m 36  n 1 prime  37
 m 37  n 2 prime  53
 m 38  n 9 prime  6599
 m 39  n 10 prime  10039
 m 40  n 1 prime  41
 m 41  n 60 prime  12960041
 m 42  n 1 prime  43
 m 43  n 2 prime  59
 m 44  n 75 prime  31640669
 m 45  n 2 prime  61
 m 46  n 1 prime  47
 m 47  n 18 prime  105023
 m 48  n 5 prime  673
 m 49  n 20 prime  160049
 m 50  n 3 prime  131
 m 51  n 2 prime  67
 m 52  n 1 prime  53
 m 53  n 12 prime  20789
 m 54  n 85 prime  52200679
 m 55  n 2 prime  71
 m 56  n 3 prime  137
 m 57  n 2 prime  73
 m 58  n 1 prime  59
 m 59  n 30 prime  810059
 m 60  n 1 prime  61
 m 61  n 4 prime  317
 m 62  n 21 prime  194543
 m 63  n 2 prime  79
 m   64  all composite  
 m 65  n 6 prime  1361
 m 66  n 1 prime  67
 m 67  n 2 prime  83
 m 68  n 3 prime  149
 m 69  n 10 prime  10069
 m 70  n 1 prime  71
 m 71  n 6 prime  1367
 m 72  n 1 prime  73
 m 73  n 2 prime  89
 m 74  n 255 prime  4228250699
 m 75  n 4 prime  331
 m 76  n 3 prime  157
 m 77  n 6 prime  1373
 m 78  n 1 prime  79
 m 79  n 10 prime  10079
 m 80  n 27 prime  531521
 m 81  n 2 prime  97
 m 82  n 1 prime  83
 m 83  n 72 prime  26873939
 m 84  n 5 prime  709
 m 85  n 2 prime  101
 m 86  n 3 prime  167
 m 87  n 2 prime  103
 m 88  n 1 prime  89
 m 89  n 570 prime  105560010089
 m 90  n 11 prime  14731
 m 91  n 2 prime  107
 m 92  n 3 prime  173
 m 93  n 2 prime  109
 m 94  n 5 prime  719
 m 95  n 18 prime  105071
 m 96  n 1 prime  97
 m 97  n 2 prime  113
 m 98  n 3 prime  179
 m 99  n 10 prime  10099
 m 100  n 1 prime  101
 m 101  n 96 prime  84934757
 m 102  n 1 prime  103
 m 103  n 4 prime  359
 m 104  n 45 prime  4100729
 m 105  n 8 prime  4201
 m 106  n 1 prime  107
 m 107  n 24 prime  331883
 m 108  n 1 prime  109
 m 109  n 30 prime  810109
 m 110  n 3 prime  191
 m 111  n 2 prime  127
 m 112  n 1 prime  113
 m 113  n 6 prime  1409
 m 114  n 5 prime  739
 m 115  n 2 prime  131
 m 116  n 3 prime  197
 m 117  n 4 prime  373
 m 118  n 3 prime  199
 m 119  n 60 prime  12960119
 m 120  n 7 prime  2521
 m 121  n 2 prime  137
 m 122  n 57 prime  10556123
 m 123  n 2 prime  139
 m 124  n 45 prime  4100749
 m 125  n 42 prime  3111821
 m 126  n 1 prime  127
 m 127  n 4 prime  383
 m 128  n 9 prime  6689
 m 129  n 50 prime  6250129
 m 130  n 1 prime  131
 m 131  n 6 prime  1427
 m 132  n 5 prime  757
 m 133  n 2 prime  149
 m 134  n 75 prime  31640759
 m 135  n 2 prime  151
 m 136  n 1 prime  137
 m 137  n 6 prime  1433
 m 138  n 1 prime  139
 m 139  n 10 prime  10139
 m 140  n 9 prime  6701
 m 141  n 2 prime  157
 m 142  n 3 prime  223
 m 143  n 6 prime  1439
 m 144  n 5 prime  769
 m 145  n 4 prime  401
 m 146  n 3 prime  227
 m 147  n 2 prime  163
 m 148  n 1 prime  149
 m 149  n 30 prime  810149
 m 150  n 1 prime  151
 m 151  n 2 prime  167
 m 152  n 3 prime  233
 m 153  n 4 prime  409
 m 154  n 115 prime  174900779
 m 155  n 6 prime  1451
 m 156  n 1 prime  157
 m 157  n 2 prime  173
 m 158  n 3 prime  239
 m 159  n 10 prime  10159
 m 160  n 3 prime  241
 m 161  n 12 prime  20897
 m 162  n 1 prime  163
 m 163  n 2 prime  179
 m 164  n 15 prime  50789
 m 165  n 2 prime  181
 m 166  n 1 prime  167
 m 167  n 12 prime  20903
 m 168  n 13 prime  28729
 m 169  n 10 prime  10169
 m 170  n 3 prime  251
 m 171  n 16 prime  65707
 m 172  n 1 prime  173
 m 173  n 132 prime  303595949
 m 174  n 35 prime  1500799
 m 175  n 2 prime  191
 m 176  n 3 prime  257
 m 177  n 2 prime  193
 m 178  n 1 prime  179
 m 179  n 720 prime  268738560179
 m 180  n 1 prime  181
 m 181  n 2 prime  197
 m 182  n 3 prime  263
 m 183  n 2 prime  199
 m 184  n 5 prime  809
 m 185  n 6 prime  1481
 m 186  n 5 prime  811
 m 187  n 4 prime  443
 m 188  n 3 prime  269
 m 189  n 290 prime  7072810189
 m 190  n 1 prime  191
 m 191  n 6 prime  1487
 m 192  n 1 prime  193
 m 193  n 4 prime  449
 m 194  n 45 prime  4100819
 m 195  n 2 prime  211
 m 196  n 1 prime  197
 m 197  n 6 prime  1493
 m 198  n 1 prime  199
 m 199  n 50 prime  6250199
 m 200  n 3 prime  281
 m 201  n 4 prime  457
 m 202  n 3 prime  283
 m 203  n 6 prime  1499
 m 204  n 5 prime  829
 m 205  n 4 prime  461
 m 206  n 21 prime  194687
 m 207  n 2 prime  223
 m 208  n 7 prime  2609
 m 209  n 30 prime  810209
 m 210  n 1 prime  211
 m 211  n 2 prime  227
 m 212  n 3 prime  293
 m 213  n 2 prime  229
 m 214  n 5 prime  839
 m 215  n 6 prime  1511
 m 216  n 7 prime  2617
 m 217  n 2 prime  233
 m 218  n 9 prime  6779
 m 219  n 40 prime  2560219
 m 220  n 7 prime  2621
 m 221  n 24 prime  331997
 m 222  n 1 prime  223
 m 223  n 2 prime  239
 m 224  n 15 prime  50849
 m 225  n 2 prime  241
 m 226  n 1 prime  227
 m 227  n 6 prime  1523
 m 228  n 1 prime  229
 m 229  n 130 prime  285610229
 m 230  n 3 prime  311
 m 231  n 4 prime  487
 m 232  n 1 prime  233
 m 233  n 24 prime  332009
 m 234  n 5 prime  859
 m 235  n 2 prime  251
 m 236  n 3 prime  317
 m 237  n 14 prime  38653
 m 238  n 1 prime  239
 m 239  n 30 prime  810239
 m 240  n 1 prime  241
 m 241  n 2 prime  257
 m 242  n 9 prime  6803
 m 243  n 4 prime  499
 m 244  n 25 prime  390869
 m 245  n 12 prime  20981
 m 246  n 7 prime  2647
 m 247  n 2 prime  263
 m 248  n 15 prime  50873
 m 249  n 50 prime  6250249
 m 250  n 1 prime  251
 m 251  n 18 prime  105227
 m 252  n 5 prime  877
 m 253  n 2 prime  269
 m 254  n 45 prime  4100879
 m 255  n 2 prime  271
 m 256  n 1 prime  257
 m 257  n 6 prime  1553
 m 258  n 5 prime  883
 m 259  n 10 prime  10259
 m 260  n 27 prime  531701
 m 261  n 2 prime  277
 m 262  n 1 prime  263
 m 263  n 6 prime  1559
 m 264  n 25 prime  390889
 m 265  n 2 prime  281
 m 266  n 3 prime  347
 m 267  n 2 prime  283
 m 268  n 1 prime  269
 m 269  n 30 prime  810269
 m 270  n 1 prime  271
 m 271  n 6 prime  1567
 m 272  n 3 prime  353
 m 273  n 10 prime  10273
 m 274  n 35 prime  1500899
 m 275  n 6 prime  1571
 m 276  n 1 prime  277
 m 277  n 2 prime  293
 m 278  n 3 prime  359
 m 279  n 40 prime  2560279
 m 280  n 1 prime  281
 m 281  n 12 prime  21017
 m 282  n 1 prime  283
 m 283  n 6 prime  1579
 m 284  n 15 prime  50909
 m 285  n 4 prime  541
 m 286  n 3 prime  367
 m 287  n 6 prime  1583
 m 288  n 7 prime  2689
 m 289  n 10 prime  10289
 m 290  n 21 prime  194771
 m 291  n 2 prime  307
 m 292  n 1 prime  293
 m 293  n 18 prime  105269
 m 294  n 5 prime  919
 m 295  n 2 prime  311
 m 296  n 9 prime  6857
 m 297  n 2 prime  313
 m 298  n 3 prime  379
 m 299  n 150 prime  506250299
 m 300  n 19 prime  130621
 m 301  n 2 prime  317
 m 302  n 3 prime  383
 m 303  n 10 prime  10303
 m 304  n 5 prime  929
 m 305  n 6 prime  1601
 m 306  n 1 prime  307
 m 307  n 4 prime  563
 m 308  n 3 prime  389
 m 309  n 20 prime  160309
 m 310  n 1 prime  311
 m 311  n 6 prime  1607
 m 312  n 1 prime  313
 m 313  n 4 prime  569
 m 314  n 45 prime  4100939
 m 315  n 2 prime  331
 m 316  n 1 prime  317
 m 317  n 6 prime  1613
 m 318  n 7 prime  2719
 m 319  n 20 prime  160319
 m 320  n 3 prime  401
 m 321  n 2 prime  337
 m 322  n 5 prime  947
 m 323  n 6 prime  1619
 m   324  all composite  
 m 325  n 6 prime  1621
```

===========================================